# Distance geometry and pythagorean theory. Pairwise distances to absolute 2D coordinates

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, pythagorean-triples

1. I don't have sufficient mathematical background.
2. I am trying to get the absolute 2D coordinates from the pairwise comparison distances:

What I have distances between points: p1-p2 = 0.3 p1-p3 = 0.5...p1-p700 = 0.1 and the same for p2...pN. What I want to have - to plot them in 2D and have coordinates, like p1(0, 0) pN(10, 10), p2(2, 6) etc...

3. I have already read/discovered/thought on the following things:

   - My data may not be (most probably, cause there are 10K comparisons) in one plane, which could give me the 2D coordinates
   - Data dimensionality can be reduced
   - I thought I could use Pythagorean theory. I.e. I take two points (I am not sure, but I think the best decision would be to use two points with distance, equal to difference of 50%) and using the distances of any other point between those two (i.e. point3-point1 = 0.23, point3-point2 = 0.57 and point1-point2 = 0.5, which 'set up the space') I can calculate the absolute coordinate in 2D space. Is my assumption right or wrong?

If it's wrong what else should I use?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. Are your points in the $(x,y)$ plane or not? How many points are involved? Do you know the distance of every point to any other point? You should restate your question in a clearer way, if you want some help.

Comment: @Aretino I've read even more and found out that I need multidimensional scaling. Or at least seems to be so. What I have distances between points: p1-p2 = 0.3 p1-p3 = 0.5...p1-p700 = 0.1 and the same for p2...pN. What I want to have - to plot them in 2D and have coordinates, like p1(0, 0) pN(10, 10), p2(2, 6) etc...

Comment: Just checking whether I understand: You have several hundred points $p_{i}$ (in some high-dimensional Cartesian space?), but you only know the distances $d_{ij} = d(p_{i}, p_{j})$ between each pair of points. These points may not be coplanar. Your goal is to represent these points in some plane so that the planar distances are equal (or as nearly equal as possible) to the known distances $d_{ij}$. Is that about right?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang yes, I know dij=d(pi,pj) for each pair of points. I haven't tested them for being coplanar. But most probably they are not (there are 10K of them or about). Yes, I want to have them all in one plane and yes, of course the distances in the plane must be as close to the dij as possible. As for the output I would like to have coordinates rather than distances, though I can get coordinates from the distances.

Comment: Possibly on a tangent, do you know about [principal component analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis)? If not, would it suit your needs?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang already know))) So, seems to be it. Read [this thing](http://www.cs.haifa.ac.il/~rita/uml_course/lectures/PCA_MDS.pdf) and [this thing](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14002/whats-the-difference-between-principal-components-analysis-and-multidimensional) I am now confused. I think I will try to write two test algorithms. Maybe it will help me a bit.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I've read this: `In MDS you try to project n-dimensional data points to a (usually) 2-dimensional  space in a manner  that similar points in the n-dimensional space will project to near distances in a plane: you´re projecting a multidimensional space preserving the inter point distances, employing distance and a loss function to analyze the proximities of data points, while in PCA you project a multidimensional space to the directions of maximum variability using covariance/correlation matrix to analyze the correlation between data points and variables.`

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang here[https://www.researchgate.net/post/Why_are_plots_of_PCA_factor_loadings_so_different_to_MDS_plots_of_the_same_data] Is it right? Judging by this explanation, I need MDS. Am I right?

Comment: I couldn't find the researchgate question you refer to, and in any case I'm a geometer, not a data analysis expert. :) As you may know, Wikipedia has a page on [multi-dimensional scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling), according to which MDS is implemented in a variety of software packages, particularly, in R and Matlab. If your question is "how do I code MDS?", the best answer is probably to use existing software.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang No, no, no. Thanks Universe, I am good at coding. Just when I asked, I didn't know about MDS. But after I asked I kept reading, so I found about the MDS. Though I am still unsure. My first attempt was Pythagorean, which has pretty much distorted the picture. Can you see this question: https://www.researchgate.net/post/Why_are_plots_of_PCA_factor_loadings_so_different_to_MDS_plots_of_the_same_data
By the way, it's very cool that you are a geometer)))